# Why is :hover acting on the colored bar and the logo?

Tags: html, css

I would only like it to act on hovering of the logo, not the colored bar.  I'm sure it's a really simple reason, I just can't figure it out.

Here is a JSFiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/3PgRv/

```
<header>
    <a href="index.html"><h1 id="logo">Dogeify</h1></a>
</header> 

header {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .9;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

#logo:hover {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  opacity: .9;
  font-family:"Comic Sans","Comic Sans MS","Arial";
  color: #7ab800;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It works fine in your fiddle.

Comment: Your "logo" is width 100% as well.  put a background-color on your logo to see what I mean.

Comment: And the duplicate answers are coming :)

Comment: i knew it was obvious!, cant believe i missed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logo is as wide as the bar. Add `display: inline` to fix it.

```
#logo {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the width of the H1 element is all the way across the container. Set a specific width and then only that area will trigger.

add to logo:

```
#logo{
  width:100px;
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Per Hashem's comment below, try setting the element to `display: inline-block` This is more flexible .

Comment: Or setting `#logo { display: inline-block; }` **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/3PgRv/1/)**

Comment: @HashemQolami Actually, that's a better solution as it's more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

The headline elements (`<h1>` et al) are by default block-level elements, so your `#logo` actually spans the entire `<header>`.

Answer (score 1):

More simple - place the `<h1>` outside the link:

```
<h1><a id="logo" href="#">Doge</a></h1>
```

**H1** spreads 100% across the parent width. But by using it outside your `#logo` tag, you ensure that only the link text is hoverable.